# Cannot read property 'subject' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to create an app with node, express, and mongo that templates emails but I've run into an error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'subject' of undefined`

Here's the relevant code:

app.js

```
app.post('/request', function(req, res){
  var request = new requestInfo({
    subject: req.body.subject,
    toName: req.body.toName,
    toEmail: req.body.toEmail,
    feeWaiver: req.body.feeWaiver,
    request : req.body.request
  });


  request.save(function(err) {
     res.redirect('/review')
  });
});
app.get('/review', function(req,res){
    res.render('review', {
      user: req.user,
      subject: req.request.subject,
      toName: req.request.toName,
      toEmail: req.request.toEmail,
      feeWaiver: req.request.feeWaiver,
      request : req.request.request,
      firstName: req.user.firstName,
      lastName: req.user.lastName,
      myOrg: req.user.myOrg,
      myPosition: req.user.myPosition,
      myPhone: req.user.myPhone,
      myAddress: req.user.myAddress,
      myAddressTwo: req.user.myAddressTwo,
      myTown: req.user.myTown,
      myState: req.user.myState,
      myZip: req.user.myZip
    });

});
```

request.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var requestInfo = new mongoose.Schema({
    subject : String,
    toName : String,
    feeWaiver : Boolean,
    toEmail : String,
    resolved : { type: Boolean, default: false},
    date : { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    request : String,
    siteUser_id : String
});

requestInfo.virtual('requestId').get(function() {
    return this._id;
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Request', requestInfo);
```

request.jade

```
extends layout

block content
    p To: #{toEmail} Subject: #{subject}
    p My name is #{firstName} #{lastName} and I am a #{position} at #{myOrg}. I am requesting the following information under the Illinois Freedom of Information Act:
    p #{request}
    if feeWaiver
      p I ask that you waive any and all fees associated with the gathering of this information as I am collecting and reporting on this information in the public interest.
    p I also ask that you cite reasons for any redactions pursuant to Illinois FOIA law.
    p My contact info is as follows:
    p #{firstName} #{lastName}
    p #{myAddress}
    p #{myAddressTwo}
    p #{myTown}, #{myState} #{myZip}
    p Phone: #{myPhone}
    <br>
    p Much appreciated,
    p #{firstName} #{lastName}
```

I think my error may have something to do with /request not passing the information on to /review but I feel like /review should still be able to pull the data from mongodb. Also, if I comment out all of the info from the request model in /review, it properly displays all of the user model data.

Comment: Where are you loading the data from mongodb into `req.request`? I think you're missing that step...

Comment: I can't see all the code, but ensure you are running Express's `bodyParser` for getting `req.body.xyz`.

Comment: Yes, I have bodyParser working because I am able to get the user info from the signup page. It certainly has to do with me not pulling the mongodb document into ```req.request```, however, I'm not sure how to do that. I am using passport to save the user information to ```req.user``` via the login() method but I'm not sure how to create a method to do that for the request information.